# Is it The Johnsons or The Johnson's

Tags: apostrophe

When you are saying The Johnson Family is is The Johnsons or The Johnson's?

Comment: 1. [**Party at the Johnsons's?**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119530/party-at-the-johnsonss), 2. [**Jones's or Jones'?**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35654/joness-or-jones) 3. [**The Jones's, Joneses, or Jones'?**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204185/the-joness-joneses-or-jones) 4. [**The Smiths vs. The Smiths’**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77565/re-a-sign-on-your-residence-the-smiths-vs-the-smiths)

Comment: You could also argue that this question has been answered here: [**Pluralization of names**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39150/pluralization-of-names)

Answer (score -1):

"The Johnsons" is the correct answer.

"The Johnson's" is a possessive form of the proper noun, as in the Johnson's house, the Johnson's blasé attitude towards telemarketers, The Johnson's willingness to run from danger, etc.

Comment: But of course it is possessive only for someone (or something) called "The Johnson".

Comment: If there's more than one Johnson, it should be the Johnsons' house.  If there's only one, it should be Johnson's house.